# How to add the "Action Bar Icon Pack" to Android Studio

Tags: android, icons, pack

I've just downloaded the Action Bar Icon Pack from https://developer.android.com/design/downloads/index.html, and I've not been able to figure out a way to "install" these icons in Android Studio... Should I copy&paste it to the res/drawable folder, one by one? Or is there some dir where I could unzip them all?

Comment: just copy items that you need (one by one)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `Action Bar Icon Pack` is similar to the a normal `drawable resource` that is used in the any project. The purpose of this is for `designer` to have a `guideline` to `develop new icons or customize existing icons` using tools like `Illustrator`

To answer your question -

Use Existing icons - copy/past the icons to desired res/drawable folder as you wish to use it.

Create/Edit icons - Import the icons to your Image Editor's(eg. Illustrator) to edit/create icons.